# Get rows where field equal value in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

```
$crud->set_table('pages',"where permission =1"); <----------------------how to do this in the right way 
$crud->set_relation('pagetype','themes','name'); 
$crud->set_rules('systemTTL', 'System Title', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean|alpha_dash'); 
$crud->callback_add_field('title',array($this,'edit_field_callback'));
```

Hellooo
I have multiple users with permissions and i want to show only raws which are for certain user group  ....

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the where method:

```
$crud->where('permission', 1);
```

**Edit:**
[Here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/where) is the documentation.

Comment: do explain why and what it does... give a man a fish and you feed him for a day, teach him to fish and you give him a lifetime of food.

Comment: It's as easy as looking at the documentation: http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/where

Comment: i looked i don't know why i didn't see it :|

Comment: with where you tell grocery crud to add the corresponding where string to the sql query. this example would make `WHERE permission = 1`. I'll try to explain better next time, sorry.